# get numbers from user & print maximum and minimum (w/o using built-in function)

Tags: python, list, max, minimum

I'm reviewing a python exercise which does the following :

- reads list of numbers til "done" gets
  entered.
- When "done" is inputted, **print
  largest and smallest of the
  numbers**.
- And it should be **without directly
  using** the built-in functions, max()
  and min().

Here is my source.
Traceback says, "'float' object is not iterable"

I think my errors are coming from not using the list properly to calculate smallest and largest. 
Any tips and help will be greatly appreciated!

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    if inp == 'done' : 
        break

    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue                            

numbers = list(num)
minimum = None       
maximum = None

for num in numbers :                          
    if minimum == None or num < minimum :
        minimum = num

for num in numbers :        
    if maximum == None or maximum < num :
        maximum = num

print 'Maximum:', maximum
print 'Minimum:', minimum
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need a list.  You should only need to keep track of the current minimum and maximum as you go.

```
minimum = None
maximum = None

while True:
    inp = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    if inp == 'done': 
        break

    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue                            

    if minimum is None or num < minimum:
        minimum = num

    if maximum is None or num > maximum:
        maximum = num

print 'Maximum:', maximum
print 'Minimum:', minimum
```

Comment: Why is the "is None" part necessary in the if statements? Seemed to me that it should run even without that, since something like if 50>None (when minimum=None) work fine

Comment: Your example refers to two different things. `50 > None` would be when `maximum = None`. And while it's true that `50 > None == True`, `50 < None == False` which would leave `minimum` unset. IIRC, under the hood when you compare two completely unrelated types and the appropriate comparison function (e.g. `__gt__(self, rhs)`) is undefined, both objects are converted to their hashes (see the `hash` function and `__hash__(self)` special method) and these are compared. On my box, `hash(None) == -9223372036576818980`, and `hash(x) == x` for any integer `x`.

Comment: TL;DR: When using `None` to represent concepts like "nil" or "NULL" or "undefined", it's best (and clearest) to give those cases their own comparison (and IMHO to prefer `is` or `is not` over `==` or `!=` so a bug in an operator overload doesn't bite you).

Answer (score 3):

With `num = float(inp)` you only assign a single number and overwrite it each time a new one is assigned. You have to create the list first, then add numbers to it each time. Something like this:

```
nums = []
while True:
  ...
  nums.append(float(inp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_set = []
input_num = 0

while (input_num >= 0):

    input_num = int(input("Please enter a number or -1 to finish"))
    if (input_num < 0):
        break
    input_set.append(input_num)

print(input_set)

largest = input_set[0]
for i in range(len(input_set)):

    if input_set[i] > largest:
        greatest = input_set[i]

print("Largest number is", greatest)



smallest = input_set[0]
for i in range(len(input_set)):

    if input_set[i] < largest:
        smallest = input_set[i]

print("Smallest number is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 def max(data):
    l = data[0]
    s = data[0]
    for num in data:
        if num > l:
            l = num
        elif num < s:
            s = num
    return l, s
    print(max([0, 10, 15, 40, -5, 42, 17, 28, 75]))
```