# Finding minimum and maximums in python without lists

Tags: python-3.x, max, user-input, minimum

So I need to write a code to find the minimum and maximum number from a set of integers inputted by a user but I am not allowed to use lists. This is what my code looks like so far.

```
sum = 0
counter = 0
done = False 
while not done:
    integer_input = int(input("Please enter a number.")) 
    if counter < 9:
        counter += 1
        sum = sum+integer_input
    else:
        done = True 
print("The average of your numbers is:", sum/10,"The minimum of your  numbers is:" "The maximum of your numbers is:")
```

Is there a for loop I could use or something from the math module possibly?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938062/get-numbers-from-user-print-maximum-and-minimum-w-o-using-built-in-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your code: You can set a `min_` and a `max_`, and then compare the integer input each time. if your input is less then `min_`, overwrite that variable. If it is greater than `max_`, overwrite that variable:

```
sum_ = 0
counter = 0
done = False
while not done:
    integer_input = int(input("Please enter a number."))
    if counter == 0:
        min_ = integer_input
        max_ = integer_input
    if counter < 9:
        if integer_input < min_:
            min_ = integer_input
        if integer_input  > max_:
            max_ = integer_input
        counter += 1
        sum_ = sum_+integer_input
    else:
        done = True 


print("The average of your numbers is:{}, The minimum of your numbers is: {}, The maximum of your numbers is: {}".format(sum_/10, min_, max_))
```

Example input:

```
Please enter a number.1
Please enter a number.2
Please enter a number.3
Please enter a number.4
Please enter a number.5
Please enter a number.6
Please enter a number.5
Please enter a number.4
Please enter a number.3
Please enter a number.2
>>> print("The average of your numbers is:{}, The minimum of your numbers is: {}, The maximum of your numbers is: {}".format(sum_/10, min_, max_))
The average of your numbers is:3.3, The minimum of your numbers is: 1, The maximum of your numbers is: 6
```